# Attaching device information to a refresh token in OpenID Connect

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

We have implemented an OIDC authentication/identity server using IdentityServer4 for .NET Core. This is a private solution, with all clients being known well ahead of time.

I would like to attach additional metadata to a stored refresh token for the purposes of identifying specific user devices and revoking their access when the end user or customer services user requests it. One possible approach to this is to have the authorization request from the client to the authentication server also contain additional context.

After reading the specification to some extent on this matter, two such parameters seem to exist, allowing additional context to be added during the authorization request. Are these parameters appropriate for this purpose? They are:

ACR - Authentication Context Class Reference

AMR - Authentication Methods References

AMR seems to fit my purposes, but I want to make sure this is the appropriate way to achieve what we're going for.

I'm also interested in alternatives, such as detecting devices via JavaScript, alternate channels for retrieving this information, soliciting this data from the user directly... please feel free to suggest an alternative approach.

Update: From comments below, it seems AMR are already enumerated, and not suited for this purpose.

Comment: AMR values are regitered at: https://www.iana.org/assignments/authentication-method-reference-values/authentication-method-reference-values.xhtml#amr-values

Comment: @jwilleke thank you, this is really cool!